# Usin Griffin Powermate in Dart

Tags: dart, hid

I know this sounds weird, but I am making a program in Dart in browser that takes input from the Griffin Powermate USB know controller. So far, I have been using the included drivers and mapped a click on the knob to a click on the mouse. Now I have run into a problem with this: The default drivers send both "buttonDown" and "buttonUp" events at the time of release, and nothing at the time when I would expect "buttonDown"-events.

I assume I will have to ignore the drivers and dive into the details. So I have the following questions:

1. Is there a magical driver replacement(preferably for OSX, but I can install another OS) that fixes the problem immediately?
2. Is there a way to access generic USB HID devices in Dart? (like 'node-hid' for node.js)

Comment: This is not Dart or programming related. http://serverfault.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think it is. He is actually looking to a Dart equivalent of Node.js's node-hib library or a way to implement something similar in Dart.

Comment: Couldn't find anything about node-hib. Node.js is server-side. In the browser you can only do what the Browser-API provides, even with Dart. The click events are produced by the operating system. This is outside the browser and I think you have to solve this problem outside the browser and thus not in Dart.

Comment: It turns out that Chrome has its own USB-API, though no support for Dart. 
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb
For other browsers I guess low-level USB-access is out of the question. 
I solved the problem by writing a replacement driver in C.